# Distribute compiled Crystal binary for macOS without brew

Tags: macos, crystal-lang

I'd like to distribute a Crystal app compiled for macOS. I'd rather not ask my users to install Brew and then Crystal dependancies. I just like to let them download my single file binary. Is this theoretically possible?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html Apple does not support static linking...

Comment: @halfelf Would it be possible tot distribute a fat binary? Or another strategy? Golang can do it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with golang or any other language. The page doesn't mean you can't do that, but not recommended and may broken in the future.

Comment: Sorry for being so naive. Is a single fat binary statically linked?

Comment: I'm going to investigate https://enclose.io. They create a fat binary by using SquashFS which is mounted JIT at runtime

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

My mistake

## [Apple does not support statically linked binaries](http://Apple%20does%20not%20support%20statically%20linked%20binaries)

Hence the following is untrue for macOS, but will work on Linux.

---

> I this this theoretically possible?

Yes! Very possible; in fact you don't need to do anything out of the normal building, crystal dependencies are statically linked into a single file. (EDIT: Not...)

Meaning: given your program `myprog`, just build it with:

```sh
$ crystal build --release src/myprog.cr
```

Crystal will then build an executable file `myprog`, and that's it! The built executable is ready to be distributed.

`myprog` will work on other macOS systems, they don't need to have any of the crystal dependencies of your program installed on their machines, this is because they're compiled into the `myprog` file.

> Note: `--release` will optimize the executable at the cost of longer build-time. Optionally you can also pass a `--no-debug` flag which will strip debug symbols from the executable and somewhat decrease the size of the file.

Comment: (just make sure you have static versions of any dependency libraries it ends up using...which you might already :)

Comment: --release does not give me a working version on a system without brew and crystal. I get an dylib loading error... $ ./staticappcrystal
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/bdw-gc/lib/libgc.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pim/Desktop/staticappcrystal
  Reason: image not found

Comment: @rogerdpack how can I install static versions of crystals core dependencies?

Comment: I tried `crystal build --release --static foo.cr` and got an error message `ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`

Comment: Yep @mipmip, Apple does not support statically linked binaries: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html.
I'm sorry, my mistake.